# Dynamic complex logic for Flink streaming?

Tags: apache-flink

I want a Flink streaming job running for long-term. The computation logic is complex and dynamic. I can use another config stream and broadcast state to implement the dynamic update of logic. However the logic I need sometimes maybe extremely complicated which means it is difficult to make a configuration pattern.

Therefore I'm considering using scripts(groovy, python, ruby and etc.) to implements the processing logic and sending it to the config stream. Flink then call parser to execute such logics to compute the result.

Does my plan work in this case? Any ideas about alternative approaches? Thank you very much!